# Application or timetracking

Tags: applications, system-apps, app-drawer

Is there any android app to monitor the time you have worked with another app in the android device?
I want to see how many hours I use an app in a day.

Comment: Asking for apps is off topic

Answer (score 1):

You can simply dial `*#*#4636#*#*` in your native dialer.

You will receive a list of options :

**Phone information**

**Battery information**

**Usage statistics**

**Wi-Fi information**

Third option is what you might want to choose.
Sort the results by *Launch count*, and you will receive the list of apps in descending order of usage time.